System of difference equations with complex numbers
Solve the equation $z_{n} = \overline{z_{n}} + iz_{n}$ for $z_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$.
I´ve gotten this far. Put $z_{n} = x_{n} + iy_{n}$ where $x_{n}, y_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
x_{n+1} + y_{n+1} = x_{n}-y_{n} + i(x_{n}+iy_{n}) = x_{n}-y_{n} + (x_{n}-y_{n})i
$$
We have the linear system
$$
x_{n+1} = x_{n}-y_{n}
$$
$$
y_{n+1} = x_{n}-y_{n}.
$$
From this we get $x_{n+1} - y_{n+1} = 0$, so $x_{n} = y_{n}$ for all $n \geq 0$. This means that the solutions are of the form
$$
z_{n} = x_{n}(1+i)
$$
where $x_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $n\geq 0$.
Is this correct?

You missed a $i$ in the second equation when substituting $z_n = x_n + i y_n$.  Moreover, you can verify if your solution is correct or not rather simply: just substitute it in the original difference equation

Presumably you mean $z_{n+1} = ...$ when you write the difference equation.  Further, you must have an initial value/condition, so say $z_0$ is given to you and need not be a real number.  Normally then expressing $z_n$ concisely in terms of $n, z_0$ and any other constant(s) would be called a closed form solution, what you have done is a bit short of that.

But how do I know the initial value if the problem doesn't say it?
